# issue with executing the query with batch separator semicolon

Tags: sql, t-sql

Happy Friday,

Just happened to encounter this issue,

When I try to execute the below query:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] DEFAULT VALUES; go 777
```

It gave me the syntax error message, but if I run this:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] DEFAULT VALUES;
go 777
```

It ran successfully, the only difference is the 2nd one split the query into two separate lines. I thought the TSQL will not enforce the batch separator should never share the line with the other clause, or is there anything I missed here? Most likely it will be a stupid question but never notice this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go):

> A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command.
>   However, the line can contain comments.

Comment: Thank you, I did not search for `GO`, but just semicolon :(, thanks again